# focusing on google maps api according to latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i got the code of drawing polylines in  google maps from [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple)
but i want to get the focus on the map according to the latitude and longitude, so  i added this line -> map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-122.5868225097656,45.56117947133065));
but the polyline didn't appear because the latitude and longitude are outside the screen and the line which i added (map.setCenter) didn't change anything
here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-122.5868225097656,45.56117947133065));
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-122.5868225097656,45.56117947133065),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-122.6348876953125,45.493833740092185)
  ];

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-122.5868225097656,45.56117947133065
-122.6348876953125,45.493833740092185
```

Are invalid latlong(s). That is the reason why app is not working right.

I tried to interchange the values. And working just fine.

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(45.56117947133065,-122.5868225097656));
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.56117947133065,-122.5868225097656),
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.493833740092185,-122.6348876953125)
  ];
```